# iOS13 insertObject:atIndex: object cannot be nil - crash / error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an app that worked fine until iOS was upgraded to 13. and it now crashes. The app looks up country codes from an array and then displays the relevent description.

In iOS13 we get an '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' crash, when we hit that view

The issue appears to relate to be how `NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@"` extracts the data.

For example I can replace `@"%@-%@"` with an option like `@"da-DK"` - and the app performs as expected, pulling up the "Danish (Denmark) " description, and doesn't crash.

The code is below - anyone have an idea what might have changed in iOS13? Thanks.

```
+ (NSString *) getTTSDescForDisplay:(NSString *) voiceLanguage {

    NSString *normalizedVoiceLanguage;
    NSArray *array = [voiceLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    if ([array count] != 2) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSString *first = array[0];
        NSString *second = array[1];
        normalizedVoiceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",first.lowercaseString,second.uppercaseString];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           @"ar-SA"       :@"Arabic (Saudi Arabia) ",
                           @"cs-CZ"       :@"Czech (Czech Republic) ",
                           @"da-DK"       :@"Danish (Denmark) "                       
                           };

    NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:normalizedVoiceLanguage];
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and breakpointing and stepping through `getTTSDescForDisplay`?

Comment: `[array count] != 2`, wouldn't you check instead if `count > 1` instead? Could you print `voiceLanguage` when it's crashing?

Comment: How is the `getTTSDescForDisplay:` used? I mean, you see `-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil` crash, but you're not working with a mutable array in this method. Where it crashes exactly? What are you doing with the result of this method? What the `voiceLanguage` argument contains when it crashes?

Comment: OK - I went deeper into the debugger/breakpointing and into the referring function and found it was being passed a new country code that wasn't in the list. (I appended the country code list above btw) - thanks all - will post solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it after breakpointing extensively. In the list above I was missing one of the (new? iOS13?) language codes.

I added it...

```
@"en-IN"       :@"English (India) ",
```

and this fixed the issue.